# Curl загрузка файла не зная расширения

Tags: php, curl

Использую curl
Не понимаю, как сохранять файл не зная его расширения?! Т.к. могут быть варианты:zip/xml/xls и тд.
Пробовал `$info = curl_getinfo($ch);` 
получил это:

```
    Array
(
    [url] => https://*****путь****
    [content_type] => application/vnd.ms-excel
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 837
    [request_size] => 161
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 6.440045
    [namelookup_time] => 1.8E-5
    [connect_time] => 1.8E-5
    [pretransfer_time] => 9.5E-5
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 705024
    [speed_download] => 109475
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 6.354781
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 192.168.1.220
    [local_port] => 40374
)
Array
(
    [url] => ftp://**путь***.xml
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 226
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 2.175119
    [namelookup_time] => 1.7E-5
    [connect_time] => 1.7E-5
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.023471
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 24336367
    [speed_download] => 11188522
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 24336367
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.023491
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => xx.xx.xx.xx
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 28996
    [local_ip] => 192.168.1.220
    [local_port] => 41852
)
```

если в первом случае хоть что то понятно

```
[content_type] => application/vnd.ms-excel
```

то во втором пусто, хотя явно загружаю xml

Comment: Ответ сервера - это просто какие то байты и хидеры описывающие эти байты.Хидеры указание на тело ответа, если отдающий сервер знает о том, что он отдает. Он может не знать или врать(криво настроен или контент динамический и криво запрограммирована отдача). В общем смотрите хидеры, например Content-Disposition с именем файла или пытайтесь сами составить имя файла на основе урла.

Comment: @vitidev спасибо за разъяснения, то есть я правильно понимаю что человеческого метода нет чтобы определить тип файла? И как бы лучше сразу знать что ты собрался грузить/получать, так получается?

Comment: Верно. Для вас это просто набор байт, и вы можете про него узнать из хидеров (если есть) или из урла (если он говорящий). Иначе труба.

Comment: @vitidev спасибо!